# Default Value for Custom Field

Tags: custom-fields, civireport

I have a created a custom group and a custom field within that group.

One of the Custom fields is Date.

Is there any way to autoload 'current date' (today) in the default value field Using a hook or something?

I have been googling but i am not getting any results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by using CiviCRM hooks (BuildForm).

```
($form == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
        $currentDate = date('d/m/Y');
        for ($i = 1; $i < 10000; $i++) {
            $defaults['custom_197_-' . $i] = $currentDate;
            $form->updateElementAttr('custom_197_-'. $i,array('readonly'));
        }
        $form->setDefaults($defaults);
       }
```

This is working